# How to change the Viewpoint Shading like in older Blender versions

Tags: 3d-view, shaders, light

I'm modelling **only with textures and vertex collours**, since all the extra shading and effects are game-specific and are done within the level editor (not in Blender).

In older versions of Blender, i only used the viewpoints **Texture, Solid, Wireframe and Bounding Box**.
Texture View let me see the model with vertex collours and textures without any extra shading. It showed it *exactly*, how it would be exported/appear in the game.
The Wireframe and Bounding Box viewpoints let me see the model in Vertex Paint without textures and only with vertex collours.

Now in the newer versions of Blender, i can't find any option to see my model only with vertex collours and textures. In solid view options, i can only see either vertex collours or textures, not both at the same time, and there is always extra shading there. Only the Vertex Paint let me see the model with both, but when switching to Object Mode, it's gone.

Is there any way to get the shading view to work, like it did in older Blender versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seems to be correct - with *Flat* type *Lightning* you can use *Texture* or *Vertex Paint* only, if you want use **Workbench**.

I wanted to use *Material* type, but it reflects only *Viewport Display* setup (single RGB *Color*).

So the only one way I see is use **Eevee** material.
Plug *Vertex Color* node and *Image texture* node into Mix RGB node, than directly into *Output* without any shader.

To see colours untouched you should change *Color Management* > **Standard**.

[image]